# AbstractMethodError due to method missing on a trait (library update)

Tags: scala

I have a fairly basic scenario, where I'm using a trait from an external library, add an object to a list that's a "global" in that lib:

```
// my code, list is a Seq in an object from the external library
list.add(new LibraryTrait(){ override def method() = { /* code */ } })

// from an external library, version used at compile time
trait LibraryTrait {
    def method() = {}
}

// from an external library, version used at runtime
trait LibraryTrait {
    def method() = {}
    def method2() = {}
}
```

At runtime it's failing with an `AbstractMethodError`, since the anonymous class I'm creating is missing `method2()` and the library I'm using at runtime is doing a call `list.foreach(x -> x.method2())`.

Is there anything else I can do, besides compiling against the version that's used at runtime, for it to work?

Not being a scala compiler expert I tried changing my code into this (hoping it will add the method properly):

```
list.add(new LibraryTrait(){ 
    override def method() = { /* code */ } 
    def method2() = { /* code */ } 
})
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I only see compile time declaration of `trat SomeTrait`. What do you mean by *used at run-time*? What exactly are you doing to create a new trait with the same name and different overloads?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sorry could've worded it better, `SomeTrait` is from an external library and I'm using a different version of the library during compilation time and runtime

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk but why are you using different versions?

Comment: @vsminkov I'm building against Spark 1.6 and wanted to run it against Cloudera's Spark 1.6 (bundled with their CDH) but they already added some new stuff from Spark 2.0 there. Normally I'd just say "we don't support this CDH" but it's hard to explain to people since Cloudera decided to call their impl 1.6...

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I'm pretty sure that you should try to compile using spark 2.0

Comment: @vsminkov yes I know that will work, I'm asking if there's a different solution, since I'm no expert in the Scala compiler and I'm not sure how into what form this is compiled into or why it's not possible (how Scala is linking it all) for learning purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question the fix from my post doesn't work but this seems to compile to a correct form, which works with both versions:

```
trait MyTrait extends LibraryTrait {
  def method2() {}
}

class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  override def method() = { /* code */ 
}

list.add(new MyClass)
```

This is a "hack" solution - meaning it works but I'm not sure why so if there's anyone more proficient in the ways of the compiler and could describe the difference in bytecode (anonymous class vs this solution) I'd greatly appreciate it and accept it as the answer.